# Could not find method allprbuildscript()

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I was trying to run a flutter app on an Android device in Visual Studio code. I kept receiving this error. It look like build.gradle file is causing the problem. I have been looking for solutions in Stackoverflow for hours. I still could not figure it out.
Here's the error message below:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file '/Users/user/flutter/project_app/android/build.gradle' line: 2

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Could not find method allprbuildscript() for arguments [build_2to8dwknaun45x53huade4k7l$_run_closure1@383a8beb] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This is from android/build.gradle path:

```
    allprbuildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
       
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        }
    }
    ojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And this is from android/app/build.gradle path:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.onatcipli.projectname"
        //minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling wrong.
Change `allprbuildscript` to `buildscript`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
   
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
ojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```